# Dataflow Gxt<->RequestFactory<->Server

Tags: gxt, requestfactory

Does anybody know or have a link to a simple CRUD-like example that demonstrates the interaction of GXT grid - store - requestfactory & EntityProxy.
 I already found some example applications, like:

- [Google's DynaTableRf](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/dynatablerf/src/com/google/gwt/sample/dynatablerf/client/DynaTableRf.java?r=8464)
- [Sencha's RequestFactory Grid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3arequestfactorygrid)
- Sencha's RequestFactory Binding

But:

> DynaDableRf does not use gxt grid and store (well thats oviously)
>   RequestFactory Grid does not provide full CRUD just R(filling the grid)
>   RequestFactory Binding hat too many Entitys that are managed and does not provide a Grid

You can surprise me by providing a complete example that just manages one entity in a list providing a editor when a single line of the grid is selected.
**Simple solutions are welcome!**
TIA

Answer (score 0):

came across this related link. Might be helpful. 
http://vivagwt.blogspot.in/2012/06/sencha-gxt3-requestfactory-guice-jpa.html

Comment: I've already read this a month ago but Gin and Maven confused me too much. Nevertheless thank you for mentioning. I'll work through again!